# Infopath 2010 get culture from hosting environment

Tags: sharepoint-2010, localization, infopath2010

I am looking into localizing the labels of an InfoPath 2010 form with code-behind that will be hosted in SharePoint as a browser form and get the current culture (based on the SharePoint variations) programatically in the InfoPath form. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get culture by using the [SPWeb's Locale Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.locale.aspx). You will have to reference the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll in your InfoPath project to get this to work.